# Is there a reason why my Twilio phone number won't respond to text messages even when getting the status code: 200?

Tags: java, spring-boot, twilio, ngrok

> **TO NOTE:** When you see `postmapping-url-here` and `MyOwnDefinedEntity` down where I show the code, it just means I'm trying not to reveal too much.

So I'm using `Twilio` to send and receive text messages. I've been stuck on this problem for around 3 days now, and I just can't seem to figure out how to resolve it.

I'm using `Spring Boot` as the application framework, `Gradle` as the build tool, and `VSCode` as the IDE. I'm also using `Ngrok`to create a tunnel for `localhost:8080` to run on.

When I ran it as a:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

it worked perfectly and my `Twilio` number sent a text back in response.

However, when I put it inside of its own function, call that function, and run it with the entire application, I still get the same status code of `200` from when it worked as a `main` method, but my `Twilio` number doesn't text me back.

I've tried using `@PostMapping` and `@GetMapping` as I've tried testing it out for both `POST` and `GET`.

In my send and receive code from the `Twilio` site, I've tried using `application/xml` and `application/json` for the response type.

Here's some of the code I have so far:

```
public static void TwilioRespondToSMS() {
        get("/", (req, res) -> "");
        post("/<postmapping-url-here>", (req, res) -> {
            res.type("application/xml");
            Body body = new Body
                    .Builder("This is a response to your text message")
                    .build();
            Message sms = new Message
                    .Builder()
                    .body(body)
                    .build();
            MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse
                    .Builder()
                    .message(sms)
                    .build();
            return twiml.toXml();
        });            
    }
```

This is the `main` code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationServerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationServerClass.class, args);
        //TwilioRespondToSMS();
    }

    // Whatever other code ...

}
```

I've also tried putting my function inside of:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandRunner() {
        return (args) -> {
            TwilioRespondToSMS();
            // Whatever other code ...
        }
    }
```

Here is the `@PostMapping` function:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping("/<postmapping-url-here>")
    public ResponseEntity<MyOwnDefinedEntity> getMyOwnDefinedEntity(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get MyOwnDefinedEntity : {}", id);
        Optional<MyOwnDefinedEntity> myOwnDefinedEntity = myOwnDefinedEntityRepository.findById(id);
        //if(myOwnDefinedEntity.isPresent())
        return new ResponseEntity<MyOwnDefinedEntity>(MyOwnDefinedEntity.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The example from Twilio's site showed it as a `main` function. Is there anything I need to change from that example when running it with the entire application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "When I ran it as a:" What's it here ? Can you post how you spin up SpringBoot app and your controller and spring config.

Comment: Well, when I use `main` to run it, I just press the `Run` button, and my `Twilio` number texts me back successfully. However, when I take it out of `main`, put it into its own method, and run it with the entire application, by doing a `./gradlew bootRun`, I still get a status code of `200`, but then Twilio no longer texts me back.

Comment: I am afraid, it's difficult to help you unless you specify what you mean by "it" & "that" function here. The best way is to the source code you have tried so far, include spring boot app starter, controller and how you call Twillio api.

Comment: I'll edit my question to show some of the things I have so far.

Comment: Honestly, I would have helped if you are willing to post your code. I don’t want to do guess work and figure out myself. You were talking about an example? Which one? Please be more constructive, follow guideline on StackOverflow to see how to ask a clear question.

Comment: I've added some code samples in my question. And, yeah, sorry about that. I'll make sure to read and follow the guidelines more often before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after 4 days of trying to resolve my problem, I've finally been able to come up with a solution on my own.

I figured maybe it was just a silly mistake that I've never noticed until now, but I feel like this solution wasn't very easy to come up with. So I'm going to share how I came up with this.

Before mapping the URL in my `post` function to a custom `@PostMapping` method, I was actually getting a status code of `404` because it did not recognize any `POST` request URLs to map to.

I figured the correct solution would be to use a custom made `@PostMapping`, but this just caused my `Java Spark` to be using the same port: `8080` as the port my `Spring Boot` application was running on. This is why I was not receiving any texts back from my Twilio number, even though I was getting a status code of `200`.

So here's what I did instead to fix the problem:

> First, I removed my custom `@PostMapping` function

```
@PostMapping("/<postmapping-url-here>")
    public ResponseEntity<MyOwnDefinedEntity> getMyOwnDefinedEntity(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get MyOwnDefinedEntity : {}", id);
        Optional<MyOwnDefinedEntity> myOwnDefinedEntity = myOwnDefinedEntityRepository.findById(id);
        //if(myOwnDefinedEntity.isPresent())
        return new ResponseEntity<MyOwnDefinedEntity>(MyOwnDefinedEntity.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

> I kept my function inside of:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandRunner() {
        return (args) -> {
            TwilioRespondToSMS();
            // Whatever other code ...
        }
    }
```

Finally, inside of my `TwilioRespondToSMS()`, I added in: `port(8070);`, or whatever other port number that isn't `8080`.

In this case `Java Spark` is now using `8070` through the `Ngrok` tunnel URL and `Spring Boot` is using `8080`. At this point, I've finally been successfully able to get a response text message back from my `Twilio` number while running `Spring Boot` at the same time.