# HTML Video Tag only shows background

Tags: html

I'm trying to insert a video into my html page and currently I only see a static image, not the video I would like. Am i doing something wrong here?

```
<div class="video" style="oveflow:hidden; width: 100%; height:425px;">
<video src="../static/data/israel/jerusalem.mp4" loop="true" 
muted="true" playsinline="true"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an image and direct link to the src so that we can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have `<source src="../static/data/israel/jerusalem.mp4" type="video/mp4">` inside of your `<video></video>` tags.

I'm referring to this w3schools example here:
[Inserting videos in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

> **Edit**: Wait, my answer went from being down voted and unhelpful to being the best answer? How did this happen?

Comment: Again not a requirement unless the user has multiple file types

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a possibility that you would be able to answer my question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215504/is-there-a-reason-why-my-twilio-phone-number-wont-respond-to-text-messages-even). I apologize in advance if it's an inconvenience.

Comment: 2 Professors voted both of us down but never enlighten the world with their knowledge. But both our answers were correct I guess and the owner of the question marked one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to adding the attribute `autoplay`?

Answer (score -1):

Inserting video in HTML is like the following:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="../static/data/israel/jerusalem.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: A tag with a single source file may use the syntax proposed in the question.

Comment: This is not a valid answer putting the src in the video tag is the same as what you put the only time source is required is when you have multiple video types